# Does not authenticate user django-social-auth?

Tags: python, django, django-socialauth

User clicked to link /login/steam. After that all works propetly (django.contrib.auth user instance and social_auth user instance create fine, custom pipeline works. But after when i try to use request.user in my view after login with steam i have error

> 'AnonymousUser' object is not iterable

My settings.py file

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_details',
'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_uid',
'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_user',
# custom pipeline
'markers.pipeline.add_steam_data_marker',
# 
'social.pipeline.user.get_username',
'social.pipeline.user.create_user',
'social.pipeline.social_auth.auth_allowed',
'social.pipeline.social_auth.associate_user',
'social.pipeline.social_auth.load_extra_data',
'social.pipeline.user.user_details', )
```

My custom pipeline.py in app

```
def add_steam_data_marker(strategy, details, backend, uid, *args, **kwargs):

if backend.name == 'steam':
    try:
        Model.objects.get(steam_user_id=uid)
        return redirect('/home/')
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
       Model.objects.create(
            ........,
        )

       return redirect('/model/add/')
```

Answer (score 2):

All trouble was in    AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS  don`t user social. ..... use social_core - >'social_core.backends.steam.SteamOpenId',

Comment: I getting the same problem with Facebook. But I using social_core.